# Eclipse Not Importing Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have tried to import my university work into my eclipse at home, however it claims it cannot find any of the projects.

The projects are in one folder, called programming, situated on my desktop, while my eclipse program files are in a separate folder, also on the desktop.

When opening eclipse it asks for the workspace to select, which is just where all of my projects are located on the desktop: "C:\Users\'username'\desktop\programming"

Once eclipse has loaded, i go to file, import, existing projects into workspace and select the root directory as the programming folder.

At this point, on my laptop, it then finds all of my projects and i can import them without a hitch, but on my PC, it says it is unable to find any projects to import.

I am 100% sure i am importing them correctly, as i have done the exact same process on my laptop, using exactly the same files (i transferred them from my laptop), i can't quite understand why it's not working this time.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Matt

Comment: You can create another project then drag your classes and ** and drop it into the project icon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Close eclipse
2. Delete the .metadata folder
3. Restart the eclipse
4. Eclipse will ask for new work space location
5. Provide a FRESH location
6. Now import the projects one by one
7. Don't select the option of "Copy projects into workspace"

See if this helps.

Answer (score 8):

A eclipse project have some hidden file an folders, like .classpath, .project and .settings

If your folder have not this files is not a eclipse project

Answer (score 2):

I have had encountered this problem before, and the solution for me has been to recreate the 
`workspace`.

Just delete the `.metadata` forder, this will reset all your workspace setting!.

Comment: I am now getting an error that says "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace" but there's nothing there!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and couldn't see my project (after import), which was copied from my other project. The fix for me was to delete `.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings/` and re-import the project.

```
 rm -rf .settings/
 rm .project
 rm .classpath
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to delete the .metadata folder! Try importing your project as "Projects from Folder or Archive" first. If it doesn't work, restart Eclipse and import the project as "Existing Projects into Workspace".

Answer (score 2):

#### Screenshot of problem :

[image]

#### Solution :

**1** : Go to project directory and remove the list of folders :

`.classpath`  `.project` `.settings`

**2** : Create new Directory and copy your project inside it :so suppose you are create root folder called **myworkspace** and folder project called **myproject** your new workspace directory path is : **myworksplace/myproject**

**3** : Go to **File** -> **Import** -> **General** -> **Existing Projects into Workspace**

[image]

**4** : Select your project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep the workspace area separate from your project.
Have your project in

```
c:\project\myProject
```

Remove all the eclipse related files as mentioned by @Troncador from your project directory and then reload the project into Eclipse workspace, say c:\users\xxx\myProject

This way you start fresh.

Comment: I am not having any .metadata folder.What could possibly be the reason for that? It is a spring project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers, but I was only able to solve it by changing the Workspace path of Eclipse...
huh...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem. the solution:
-close eclipse.
-then open when it asks to choose the workspace for your projects
-you choose a new location
-then you copy your [projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV7dH.png) into the new location.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem too and solved it with the solution below

```
# I try : file > import > you can choose import your project from ...
# [ General > Existing Projects ] 
# or 
# [ Git > Project form git ]
```

I think this error occurs when we copy projects into the folder workspace by ourselves.  Eclipse doesn't allow that.  They want you to use the import method. In my case, I guess it's because I clone the project from a git repository.